# Jquery change css of specific table row

Tags: jquery

I can access the row with:

```
$('#records tbody tr')[i]
```

But the object returned does not have a .css property.
Accessing

```
$('#records tbody tr').val(i)
```

returns all the rows in the table, which is not what I want, but it does have the .css property.

How can I access a specific index `i` of my table and change its css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq):

```
$('#records tbody tr:eq(0)').css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** selector:

```
 $('#records tbody tr:first').css('color','red');
```